# How can I delay my function so that it sees the window location hash?

Tags: jquery, html

I am passing values into anchors from arrays, which then need to run a function when they are clicked.
**Function**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function SetOption() {
        var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
            $('#uniform-id span').text(hash);//Changes the text in the dropdown box
            $("#select id option:contains(" + hash + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');//Takes the hash and looks for an option that contains that hash
        }
    </script>
```

**Append Function**

```
$.each(color, function (index, value) {
var anchor=$('<a class="color">').css({
    height: '30px',
    width: '30px',
    'background-color': value
}).attr({ 
    "href": "#" + colorname[index], //append colorname as hash
    "onclick": "SetOption();", //run function SetOption when clicked
});
    $('#palette').append(anchor);
});
//var columns = $("#palette > a"); this part isn't important for the question.
//for(var i = 0; i < columns.length; i+=16) {
//  columns.slice(i, i+16).wrapAll("<div class='column'></div>");
}
```

**Sample Arrays**

```
var colorname = [];
colorname [ 0 ] = "color 1";
colorname [ 1 ] = "color 2";
colorname [ 2 ] = "color 3";
colorname [ 3 ] = "color 4";

var color = [];
color[ 0 ] = 'rgb(70,60,65)';
color[ 1 ] = 'rgb(95,58,61)';
color[ 2 ] = 'rgb(79,56,57)';
color[ 3 ] = 'rgb(87,50,65)';
```

Currently the function runs before the hash can be set for the anchor tags, output html looks like this:

```
<a class="color" href="#color 1" style="height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: rgb(70, 60, 65);"></a>
```

It seems that the href for the anchor needs to be first in order for this to function, or else my function SetOption will need to be delayed.

Comment: Why do you have a whitepspace inside the `href` attribute?

Comment: have you tried it with `$(window).ready`?

Comment: @Itay I have white space in the options inside my select

Comment: @raam86 Which part would I use with window.ready? (I am still new to jQuery)

Comment: around the each. @TheEks.

Comment: Also what do you expect to happen? The output seems correct. What doesn't happen?

Comment: @raam86 No luck with that, I'm really not sure how that would affect when the function SetOption runs though, I think that is my issue at the moment.

Comment: @raam86 what doesn't happen is that the option in the select list is not actually selected because my function SetOption runs before the window.location is added. This causes SetOption to select a null/blank value from the options.

Comment: @raam86 by wrapping my onclick function in a (document).ready the function waits to run now. All set to go. Will answer my question once the system lets me.

Answer (score 1):

A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

[Source](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what this does to fix the issue I am having. I am running my function to append the anchor tags inside of a (document).ready at this time, and have tried (window).ready as well but this doesn't affect when the function SetOption runs.

Comment: Just the each function. Ended up delaying the onclick function by using setTimeout(function() { SetOption(); }, 500);

Comment: Just put all the code in the document ready block. That should cleanly solve your problem. No offense but your solution is kind of a dirty hack ;)

Comment: Absolutely a dirty hack, I don't know any other way :) I've tried putting everything in the same document ready, and having them split across multiple files as I normally do each in their own - still no luck. If I try to run my function SetOption from the console it says it's not defined, so something is off.